How to get specific user data from a table with foreignKey to another tables Django
I have 3 table

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Boost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)# point, storage, point p/s,
    expire = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    expireDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    visiblity = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "id:"+self.title

class BoostLevel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    boost = models.ForeignKey(Boost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.IntegerField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.boost.title + " level: " + self.level.__str__()
    
class UserBoostList(models.Model):
    boostLevel = models.ForeignKey(BoostLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    boostId = models.ForeignKey(Boost, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    userId = models.BigIntegerField(null=False)


In my case, Boost is a title, Boost level are levels for boost and UserBoostList are User selected boost
Each boost can have many level from 1 to X.
Each user should start boost from level 1 to level 2 and go on
I need to check each user have which level of boost for each boost
let me explain
I have Boost A and boost B in Boost table
and boosts level 1 ,2 ,3 ... for each boost separate, Ex(boost A level 1, boost A level 2  and ... AND boost B level 1 , boost B level 2 and ...)
I need to

Return Boost level 1 if user have no BoostLevel
Return Next Level of BoostLevel if user have Boosted to some level (for each Boost) if next level exist.

( get last boosted level if no next BoostLevel exist for user, and get next level in BoostLevel If next level exist in BoostLevel )
Note: You can add or remove any field to make module better if you need. but tell me about that.
I try to find best way to get info from 3 table with foreignKey.

I rewrite your Model code and changes something and add more functionality. I added a new connection between users and a list called "UserBoostList". This allows for a more direct relationship between users and their boosts then i renamed "boostId" to avoid having the same name appear twice (redundancy). Finally, I improved the way the model information is displayed (using str methods) to make it easier to understand. Now see the query function what i added. I hope it will be work for you.
Model:
            from django.db import models
            from django.contrib.auth.models import User

            class Boost(models.Model):
                title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)  # point, storage, point p/s, etc.
                expire = models.BooleanField(default=False)
                expireDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
                visibility = models.BooleanField(default=True)

                def __str__(self):
                    return self.title

            class BoostLevel(models.Model):
                boost = models.ForeignKey(Boost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                level = models.IntegerField(null=False)

                def __str__(self):
                    return f"{self.boost.title} level: {self.level}"

            class UserBoostList(models.Model):
                user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Link directly to the user
                boostLevel = models.ForeignKey(BoostLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

                def __str__(self):
                    return f"User: {self.user.username}, {self.boostLevel}"

Query:
            from django.contrib.auth.models import User
            from .models import UserBoostList

            def get_user_boost_levels(username):
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                user_boosts = UserBoostList.objects.filter(user=user).select_related('boostLevel__boost')
                
                boost_info = {}
                for user_boost in user_boosts:
                    boost_title = user_boost.boostLevel.boost.title
                    level = user_boost.boostLevel.level
                    boost_info[boost_title] = level
                
                return boost_info


I forgot to tell you, I need to get last boosted level if no next BoostLevel exist for user, and get next level in BoostLevel If next level exist in BoostLevel
